# Increase HttpClient timeout for Neo4JClient in C#

Tags: c#, neo4j, httpclient, neo4jclient

So I am running a fairly large query which works fine via the shell, but times out when using Readify's GraphClient throwing a "TaskCancelledException".

This behavior is expected since the query takes about 4 minutes to complete when using the shell and the neo4jclient uses a default timeout of 100 seconds.

My Question is: How do I increase this Timeout?

I've found this post which suggests using the IHttpClient to increase the timeout but the post is years old and I do not know how to implement the suggestion. 
http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/issue/70/taskcancelledexception

(PS: The query being ran is :

"match p = shortestPath ((a:Domain{id:"Someid"}))-[:IP]-(b:Domain))
 return nodes(p)"

in a graph of a few hundred thousand nodes.

This is not a question about optimizing my query to run faster(Although I'm open to suggestions, but putting an upper bound on the depth will not help lol), it is a necessity that I increase this timeout value!

### Thank you

Comment: This is just about the query, do you have an index on :Domain(id) ? and you actually don't have a variable length specified, so it should return immediately. How long does the query take in the Neo4j UI or shell?

Comment: Indeed, I am indexing on Domain(id) and can get the method to return faster by setting limits on depth or on the number of returns, likewise, the query completes fine in Shell, it just takes a few minutes. But this is not a matter of speed, it is a matter of allowing arbitrarily large queries to complete without TaskCancelledException being thrown which I suspect is the result of the clients underlying HttpClient's defualt timeout value.

Comment: As a note to future travelers, I have abandoned my search. I will instead be building the Neo4JClient project from source via their github and modifying the timeout in the source. Its a pretty big workaround for something that seems it should be simple. Offering a timeout option in the constructor or as a property should be standard.

Comment: Perhaps make it configurable and send a pull request to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously this is very late, but `Neo4jClient` was updated to allow you to do this, you can extend the timeout like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) };
GraphClient gc = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), new HttpClientWrapper("user", "pass", client));
```

If so inclined, you can whack it all into one line :)